# What does "for each value converted" mean in the following sentence?

Tags: c

What does "for each value converted" mean in the following sentence?

> Q: Why doesn't the call `scanf("%d", i)` work?
>
> A: The arguments you pass to `scanf` must always be pointers: **for each
>   value converted**, scanf "returns" it by filling in one of the
>   locations you've passed pointers to. (See also [question 20.1](http://www.c-faq.com/misc/multretval.html).) To fix
>   the fragment above, change it to `scanf("%d", &i)` .

I have found this in the [c-faq](http://www.c-faq.com/); it's [question 12.12](http://www.c-faq.com/stdio/scanf1.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you execute `scanf("%d", &i)` with input `123`, the character sequence `123` is *converted* to an `int` value, which is stored in `i`.

This is not a type conversion as might be specified by a cast, but it's still reasonable to refer to it as a "conversion".

Answer (score 2):

[`scanf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) can scan for more than one value in a single call.  e.g.:

```
int numConverted = scanf("%d %f %d", &myInt1, &myFloat, &myInt2);
```

Note: you should always inspect the return value to find out how many have *actually* been converted, though.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't very clear in my question. I do understand that scanf() can scan for more than one values but I don't understand what 'converted' means in this reference.

Comment: @aste123: Well, it starts as human-readable text representation, and ends up in a primitive data-type!